# Login with apple doen’t work in simulator using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14

Sign in with apple doesn’t work in simulator (issue) it keeps spinning all the time when hit login button after typing right credentials ..

but it works fine in real device
I searched on the internet and tried all the ways i found
————————————————-

- delete apple id from simulators
- deleted my app from the apps that uses apple id login
- tried another simulator and go back to the previous one but it still spinning
- and i’ve already enabled sign in with apple from xcode in debug and released and also checked it from developer site which is enabled also .

Also i found the same issue facing developes in apple site ..any help! ~~~~~~

Comment: It's a known issue if you have a search. It is really annoying but, since it's been an issue for a while, I don't see it getting fixed anytime soon. My solution was to have sign-in with apple for all users, with one test account that is an email/password account on the backend, which would be used in DEBUG mode.

Comment: @George yeah hope they are fixing itthanks but how can i acheive that (sign in with apple for all users) with one test account in the backend i didn’t get that

Comment: Well for example, in my app in development, I use Firebase Authentication as a backend. I then have a test account which can be signed in with email & password. Then, when in DEBUG mode (`#if DEBUG` ...) for the app, I am signed into a test account instead and skip sign in with apple.